Mcode, Use Excel's Power Query to manipulate data table. Copy Cell based on multiple criteria
In Excels Power Query I have a somewhat complicated query. In the Step I am working on I have a table named "FinalTable" I need to copy data from a cell in Column "C003" to another row in the same column.
The cell to be copied from is based on a value in column "C001" and the cell to be copied to is based on a value in Column "C002" Here is an example table.



C001
C002
C003




Offsite E. Florence Blvd

10462



Strata: CL/SC




Strata: SC-SM/SP/SM




Strata: End




Offsite E. Florence Blvd: Strata Total




the goal is to copy the data in (1,C003) to (5,C003). This needs to be done programmatically however as I will have different data sets and this is only a small sample.
To accomplish this I need to do the evaluate column "C001" for non blank values. If there is a non blank value then check if that value is a substring of a cell in column "C002" If it is copy the value of "C003"
The resultant table should look like this:



C001
C002
C003




Offsite E. Florence Blvd

10462



Strata: CL/SC




Strata: SC-SM/SP/SM




Strata: End




Offsite E. Florence Blvd: Strata Total
10462



I have accomplished a similar task before but that moved data across rows and not up and down a column. I also tried making a second table that was a subset of the data that removed all rows and columns not needed and then used it as a reference to try an check against but I cant seem to get it working.
Would appreciate any help, Thank you.

One way
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "C001", "zC001"),
#"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "C003", "zC003"),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Duplicated Column1",{"zC001", "zC003"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filled Down",{{"C003", "xC003"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "C003", each try if Text.Contains([C002],[zC001]) then [zC003] else [xC003] otherwise [xC003]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"xC003", "zC001", "zC003"})
in #"Removed Columns"



Thanks for the help! I attempted to use this but I think the larger data table I am using it on is causing issues? Before, After

Sorry I am unable to see your code. This example works as shown

I used the code you provided, only change was to match the source to mine, two image links there

realized the after image was pulling from the wrong data set here is the correct link It seems to be deleting C003

Sorry, perhaps someone else can help

Was able to figure out a solution inspired by the "Filled Down" command from horseyride's answer.

Starting here I had to add back in the null value in cells to allow the filled down command to work. I only added the null value where I needed based on the text contained in C001.
BlankToNull = Table.TransformRows(#"Renamed Columns", each if Text.Contains(_[C001], "Strata") then Record.TransformFields(_, {{"C002", each null}}) else _),
ExpandRecord1 = Table.FromRecords(BlankToNull),


After that I allowed the Fill Down command to populate all the null cells with values.
FilledDown = Table.FillDown(ExpandRecord1,{"C002"}),


Now I needed to clean the cells I didn't want to have the filled data in.
WhiteOut = Table.TransformRows(FilledDown, each if Text.Contains(_[C001], "Strata") and not Text.Contains(_[C001], "Total") then Record.TransformFields(_, {{"C002", each ""}}) else _),
ExpandRecord2 = Table.FromRecords(WhiteOut)


I ended up with my desired result. Key takeaway for me was how to transform multiple cells in a column based on the values of cells in other columns. Accomplished this using the Table.TransformRows() command and passing through arguments such as Text.Contains().

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"C001", type text}, {"C002", type text}, {"C003", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"C003"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filled Down", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Check Blank" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Temp", 
        each
            if
               [Index] = Table.RowCount(#"Added Index") - 1 or 
               #"Added Index"[C002]{[Index]} = null or
               #"Added Index"[C002]{[Index]+1} = null 
            then
               #"Added Index"[C003]{[Index]} else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Check Blank",{"C003", "Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Temp", "C003"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"



Oh thanks for the response! I just got a solution working and came to share it. I will compare notes.
